# What is an alternative to CSV data set config in JMeter?

Tags: csv, jmeter, credentials

We want to use 100 credentials from .csv but I would rather like to know if there is any other alternative to this available in jmeter.

Comment: There is, but why/what you need that CSV isn't letting you?

Comment: CSV is fulfilling the requirement but wanted to know better alternative if any.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the credentials in the CSV file there are no better ways of "feeding" them to JMeter than CSV Data Set Config.

Just in case if you're still looking for alternatives:

1. [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead). The disadvantage is that the function reads the whole file into memory which might be a problem for large CSV files. The advantage is that you can [choose/change the name of the CSV file dynamically (in the runtime)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) while with the CSV Data Set Config it has to be immutable and cannot be changed once it's initialized.
2. [JDBC Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) - allows fetching data (i.e. credentials) from the database rather than from file
3. [Redis Data Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/) - allows fetching data from [Redis](https://redis.io/) data storage
4. [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) - exposes simple HTTP API for fetching data from CSV (useful for [distributed architecture](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) when you want to ensure that different JMeter slaves will use the different data), this way you don't have to copy .csv file to slave machines and split it

Answer (score 0):

There are few alternatives

1. JMeter Plugin for reading random CVS data : [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md)
2. JMeter function : [__CSVRead](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)
3. Reading CSV file data from a [JSR223 Pre Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

[CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is simple, easier to user and available out of the box.